# How do you extract what units ggplot2 is using for its coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is silly, I can't be the only person who has problems aligning annotations with ggplot2 graphics.

I can't use gridBase because I'm trying to automate a complex and repetitious plotting task, so I need to get at the coordinates programmatically, and pass them as parameters to annotate before the grobs are plotted.

ggplot has access to this information. There's got to be a way for me to do so as well!

I'm surprise something this important for cleanly annotating plots isn't deliberately exposed by ggplot2 to begin with.

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without a concrete example.

Comment: Annotations within ggplot can be specified in the untransformed (data) coordinates. What sort of annotations are you talking about?

Comment: Do you need to get at a specific coordinate value, or a relative position on the grid?

Comment: ggplot2 is based on a _grammar of graphics_, which is why manual adornments are not explicitly included in the framework. There are ways though, e.g. `annotate`, `annotation_raster`, `annotation_custom`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates - or x and y scales - are set when generating the final plot. Hadley used the term "training".
This means that you have to have it plotted, either as a grob or to a device, before ggplot knows the scales.

Instead, you can explicitly tell ggplot the extend of the axis, either with [`coord_cartesian`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/coord_cartesian.html) or [`xlim`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/xylim.html). For this, you can use the `range` and `pretty` functions to determine the extent together with some nice rounding.

Comment: I'll try this with my problem and see if it solves it. Sounds logical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layer_scales(plot, i = 1L, j = 1L).`

[Check here for reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot_build.html)